# Modify/update an entry in a po file with polib in Python

Tags: python, translation, gettext, po

[polib](https://github.com/izimobil/polib/) appears to be THE library of choice for working with gettext/po files in Python. The [docs](http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) show how to iterate through message strings, save po and mo files, etc. However, it's not clear to me, how can one edit a specific entry?

Let's say, I iterate over all messages in an existing po file and display them in an HTML form with textareas. By submitting the form, I get - as an example - the original
*msgid = "Hello World"*
and the via textarea translated
*msgstr = "Hallo Welt"*

The original part inside the po file may look like this:

```
#: .\accounts\forms.py:26 .\accounts\registration\forms.py:48
msgid "Hello World"
msgstr ""
```

or with fuzzy flag set:

```
#: .\accounts\forms.py:26 .\accounts\registration\forms.py:48
#, fuzzy
msgid "Hello World"
msgstr "Hallo"
```

Now how do I update this particular translation in the actual po file? And in case this message was marked as "fuzzy", how do I remove this flag?

Any help appreciated ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, after reading through the source code of polib, I found this way to achieve, what I want:

```
entry = po.find('Email address')
if entry:
    entry.msgstr = 'E-Mail-Adresse'
    if 'fuzzy' in entry.flags:
        entry.flags.remove('fuzzy')
```

This seems to be the way to go ...

In the case of pluralisation - just as an example:

```
entry = po.find('%s hour ago')
if entry and entry.msgid_plural:
    entry.msgstr_plural['0'] = 'Vor %s Stunde'
    entry.msgstr_plural['1'] = 'Vor %s Stunden'
```

The docs of polib should definitively be updated. Otherwise great tool.

Comment: just so there is no confusion for someone else - in order to ADD a fuzzy flag you'd write:
entry.flags.append('fuzzy')
and not
entry.flags.add('fuzzy')